# Store an array of DATETIME type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to know each time an object was put inside and taken out of a container. How can I have one field for each, 'time_in' and 'time_out' (separate columns), and store a variable amount of DATETIME objects in each? Is it possible to store an array of DATETIME types in MySQL?

Comment: I have those two columns already, my question is how do I store an array of DATETIME objects into each column. would i have to serialize it and store as string?

Comment: because an item could be put inside once and taken out once, or put inside and taken out 10 times. i want a record of each time it was put in and each time it was taken out, regardless of how many times it occured

Comment: can you explain that a little further? or link to something that explains how it's executed?

Comment: fantastic, great explanation. if you put this as answer I'll mark you as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic 1:n relationship here. This can be modelled like this:

```
create table item
(
  item_id integer not null primary key
);

create table movement
(
  item_id integer not null,
  time_in timestamp not null,
  time_out timestamp not null,
  primary key (item_id, time_in), 
  foreign key (item_id) references item (item_id)
);

insert into item 
values
(1),
(2),
(3);

insert into movement (item_id, time_in, time_out)
values 
(1, timestamp '2014-02-12 00:00:00', timestamp '2014-02-12 14:17:10'),
(1, timestamp '2014-02-12 14:03:00', timestamp '2014-02-12 16:07:40'),
(1, timestamp '2014-02-12 18:00:42', timestamp '2014-02-12 22:10:05'),
(2, timestamp '2014-02-12 01:00:00', timestamp '2014-02-12 06:06:19'),
(2, timestamp '2014-02-12 15:16:17', timestamp '2014-02-12 16:17:18'),
(3, timestamp '2014-02-12 01:01:01', timestamp '2014-02-12 03:03:03'),
```

Comment: one more question. you made the primary key of movement as ('item_id','time_in'). but if an item is placed in multiple times, it doesn't have one unique value for that so would that pose a problem? wouldn't you need the first ever 'time_in' as its unique identifier?

Comment: @ejfrancis: that depends on your requirements do you allow the *same* item to enter at *exact the same time* twice? If yes, then you'll probably need a generated key. If `item` is something that has multiple "instances" (e.g. a library has 4 copies of a book) you might want to distinguish those "instances" using an additional attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I might design a table to store the `time_in` and `time_out` like below :

```
object_time

    object_time_id - Int - Auto Increment - Primary Key
    object_id - Int
    object_time - Datetime
    object_time_in_or_out - Char(1) - Default '' - 'I' for In , 'O' for Out
```

When you instantiate the object ( in the constructor ) generate a `unique id` for the object . From then on for every `time_in` and `time_out` add a new row to the above table .

If you have two separate columns for `time_in` and `time_out` , to update `time_out` , you would have to keep track of the row corresponding of the `time_in` . This can be eliminated by having just one column for both .

Comment: In general I agree, but given MySQL as a DBMS there are certain queries that would be quite a problem with this design (e.g. how long did an item stay "in" - very inefficient if you can't use window functions)